# Full page gallery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an idea for a gallery and I need some help with what jQuery plugins I'll need to make this happen.

I intend of using the jQuery [Timeline](http://www.csslab.cl/ejemplos/timelinr/latest/horizontal.html) plugin to view different years. Each year will have some text and I was hoping to have a gallery of images appearing full screen in the background (fade effect). When each year is clicked the text and a different set of images are shown.

The Timeline plugin uses list items, is there a way of implementing a plugin with this to show a list of gallery items on each item also?

This is an extract of the Timeline html:

```
<div id="timeline">
        <ul id="dates">
            <li><a href="#1900">1900</a></li>
            <li><a href="#1930">1930</a></li>
            <li><a href="#1944">1944</a></li>
            <li><a href="#1950">1950</a></li>
            <li><a href="#1971">1971</a></li>
            <li><a href="#1977">1977</a></li>
            <li><a href="#1989">1989</a></li>
            <li><a href="#1999">1999</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2001">2001</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2011">2011</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="issues">
            <li id="1900">
                <img src="images/1.png" width="256" height="256" />
                <h1>1900</h1>
                <p>Donec semper quam scelerisque tortor dictum gravida. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam pulvinar, odio sed rhoncus suscipit, sem diam ultrices mauris, eu consequat purus metus eu velit. Proin metus odio, aliquam eget molestie nec, gravida ut sapien. Phasellus quis est sed turpis sollicitudin venenatis sed eu odio. Praesent eget neque eu eros interdum malesuada non vel leo. Sed fringilla porta ligula.</p>
            </li>
            <li id="1930">
                <img src="images/2.png" width="256" height="256" />
                <h1>1930</h1>
                <p>Donec semper quam scelerisque tortor dictum gravida. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam pulvinar, odio sed rhoncus suscipit, sem diam ultrices mauris, eu consequat purus metus eu velit. Proin metus odio, aliquam eget molestie nec, gravida ut sapien. Phasellus quis est sed turpis sollicitudin venenatis sed eu odio. Praesent eget neque eu eros interdum malesuada non vel leo. Sed fringilla porta ligula.</p>
            </li>
```

What I need is a full page background gallery for each date (in each li item).

Anyone got any ideas??

Comment: That's just it I've not yet tried anything, I'm just asking to find out if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Supersized. I have used it in production and find it easy and powerful.

http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/